# MySQL Federated table crashes MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, federated-table

I just enabled Federated engine on MySQL 5.5 server. I set up a federated table on another server and made sure I had an IP passthrough setup on the server I'm connecting to on MySQL port. The connection is really slow. In MySQL workbench, initially selecting the table or especially right clicking on the table causes MySQL workbench to lock up and I have to force it to close. If it does finally let me click on it, I get an error when trying to query data:

Error Code: 1429. Unable to connect to foreign data source: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server IP' (110)

I have another MySQL server where I set up the same Federated table to the same destination server and I have no problems querying data.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Open a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 2):

I just found out the issue. It was due to MySQL not having the proper permissions. I started getting an "Error Code: 1159 Got timeout reading communication packets" message. Turned out the view I was pulling into the federated table was so huge, that it was causing timeouts. Dumping the view into a cache table and setting it up with a proper index and linking the Federated Table to the cache table solved the problem.